# Yellow exclamation mark on the Wifi icon whereas the Wifi is working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, icons

Sometimes I see a yellow exclamation mark on the Wifi icon, while the Wifi is working. What can cause the exclamation mark to appear?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Yellow exclamation mark on the Wifi icon:

[image]

Wifi's working fine:

[image]

My Wifi status:

[image]

I use a VPN through [Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The yellow exclamation mark is a connectivity warning shown when one of the networks you are connected to isn't fully functional.

Judging by your screenshot, the connectivity warning is being generated by the AdobeGuest network, where you have no internet connectivity.

If you want the warning to disappear, disconnect from AdobeGuest.

Answer (score 2):

In this case exclamation mark just means "No internet access". No need to disconnect from that network

Comment: To be more specific, it indicates that Windows cannot reach a designated test server Microsoft has configured, which could be for any number of reasons.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Hmmm... Maybe there's some truth, but my router configured to drop any outgoing traffic from my laptop, incoming blocked by firewall(blacklist), and I thought it can't reach any test server. And after sniffing I captured the packets wich I think makes the laptop know about internet access. It were google dns replies. So maybe we can state exclamation mark appears when dns server unreachable?

Comment: I don't know the specifics but I'm pretty sure at least one of the tests does include a DNS lookup, yes. A correct DNS lookup might even be the only test - it's been a long time since I read about how it worked.